# Scala Open Windows Desktop File Explorer and select Directory

Tags: scala, awt

I'm learning Scala and want to create a basic program to select a directory and filter the files based on a search term.

My program works if I code in the directory and search term.

What I want to add is a File Explorer to allow the user to select a directory. Then allow the user to enter the search term in a dialog box.

This is my code.

```
import java.awt.Desktop
import java.io.File

val directory
Desktop.getDesktop.open(new directory("C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive"))
def getListOfFiles(dir: String): List[String] = {
  val file = new File(dir)
  file.listFiles.filter(_.isFile)
    .filter(_.getName.contains("scala"))
    .map(_.getPath).toList
}
getListOfFiles("C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive")
```